# Sitecore 9.0 Installation Issue:ERROR_SCRIPTDOM_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER

Tags: sitecore-install-framework, installation

I am trying to install Sitecore Experience platform 9.0 using Sitecore via SIF.

Versions of the pre-requisite Softwares/Tools are

- SQL Server Version-14.0.1000.169,
- Sitecore XP 9.0,
- Solr-6.6.2,
- SIF 1.2

During Install WDP : WebDeploy step, I am facing  `ERROR_SCRIPTDOM_NEEDED_FOR_SQL_PROVIDER` error and couldn't proceed with further installation.

I have followed every step that was mentioned in this article https://naveed-ahmad.com/2017/11/03/sitecore-9-sif-installation-error-error_scriptdom_needed_for_sql_provider/ , but still issue continues.Thanks in advance!
[image]

Comment: Did you try installing it with another instance name? once you fail anything you have to clean everything before starting the installation setup.

Comment: I haven't renamed so far. Will do that and try. Thanks for the help @SitecoreSam.

Comment: Tried renaming it and executed. Issue still persists @SitecoreSam.

Comment: did you check you have all the windows features enabled required for the installation setup. Take a look at my article it has saved so many developers time, https://isaadansari.wordpress.com/2018/05/01/sitecore-9-installation-download-install-validate-done/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already installed all the prerequisite then make sure that you have added  missing registry `DacFxPath` and `DacFxDependenciesPath` under the registry key `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IIS Extensions\MSDeploy\3`

**Follow article** https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/019579

Key - DacFxPath

Value - `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin`

Key – DacFxDependenciesPath

Value - `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DAC\bin`

**Note-** Please clean everything before executing the installation script again

Comment: Thanks a lot.It worked after changing the registry entries as mentioned.